# Disable rounding up of PolarAxesOrigin

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.0.0 or later**

---

How to disable rounding up the radius which is used to calculate the origin of the polar axes with the option [`PolarAxesOrigin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolarAxesOrigin.html)?
Example:

```
PolarPlot[Sqrt[n], {n, 0, 20}, PolarAxes -> True,
PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 7}, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}]
```

[image: polar plot]

It rounds `7` to `8`, `13` to `15` and `521` to `600`.

Comment: Added the `bugs` tag. Feel free to remove it if I made a mistake

Comment: Should I report it to customer support?

Comment: I'd suggest waiting for a day or o to see if someone else can find a workaround

Comment: @shrx I have added the bug header. Is the introduction version correct? I don't have access to earlier version than 9.0 at the moment.

Comment: @Xavier thanks for the edit. I also don't have old versions installed anymore, but you can judge from the date the question was posted here which version was used.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like `PolarPlot` uses [`FindDivisions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindDivisions.html) internally to generate the ticks and chooses the last point as the origin, which causes this behaviour:

```
FindDivisions[{0, 7}, 4]
(* {0, 2, 4, 6, 8} *)
```

This is in fact described in the documentation for `FindDivisions` (under "Details and Options"):

> The first and last numbers may be slightly outside the range $x_\min$ to $x_\max$

I've run into similar subtle quirks with `PolarPlot` – especially when styling/customizing it a particular way — and usually end up writing my own version of `PolarPlot` using graphics primitives.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest workaround:

```
PolarPlot[Sqrt[n], {n, 0, 20}, PolarAxes -> {True, False}, 
 PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 7}, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
 Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I could almost use this, I just need to figure out how to perform `Abs[]` on major ticks while preserving the minor ticks, and how to cut off the axes at `[-7,7]`. Will look into it now.

Answer (score 2):

I have contacted Technical Support and they have confirmed this to be a bug. They have also provided the following workaround:

```
plot = PolarPlot[7 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 7}, 
PolarAxes -> True]
```

[image: initial plot]

```
(* Rescale the circular part. *)
plot[[1, 5, 1]] = Scale[plot[[1, 5, 1]], {7/8, 7/8}];

(* Remove the tick "8". *)
Cases[plot[[1, 5, 2]], Text[___], Infinity]
```

> ```
> {Text[0., Offset[{0, -8}, Scaled[{0., -0.006}, {0, 0}]], {-1, 0}], 
> Text[2., Offset[{0, -8}, Scaled[{0., -0.006}, {2, 0}]], {-1, 0}], 
> Text[4., Offset[{0, -8}, Scaled[{0., -0.006}, {4, 0}]], {-1, 0}], 
> Text[6., Offset[{0, -8}, Scaled[{0., -0.006}, {6, 0}]], {-1, 0}], 
> Text[8., Offset[{0, -8}, Scaled[{0., -0.006}, {8, 0}]], {-1, 0}]}
> ```

```
Position[plot[[1, 5, 2]], Text[___], Infinity]
```

> ```
> {{4, 1}, {4, 2}, {4, 3}, {4, 4}, {4, 5}}
> ```

```
plot[[1, 5, 2]] = Delete[plot[[1, 5, 2]], {{4, 5}}];
plot
```

[image: plot with fixed origin]

Answer (score 1):

We can use the function `fixPolarAxes` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/263384/125) to post-process `PolarPlot` output to fix polar axes/ticks/gridlines:

```
plot = PolarPlot[7 Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
  PolarAxesOrigin -> {0, 7}, PolarAxes -> True]
```

[image]

```
fixPolarAxes[7] @ plot
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[fixPolarAxes]

fixPolarAxes[radius_] := 
  Module[{maxradius = Max @ Cases[#, Circle[_, r_, _] :> r, All], scale},
   scale = radius / maxradius;
   ReplaceAll[
    {Circle[c_, maxradius, a_] :> Circle[c, radius, a] (* change angular axis radius *),
     Circle[_, r_/; r > radius,_] -> {} (* remove unwanted radial gridlines *),
     Text[_, Offset[_, Scaled[_, a_ /; Norm[a] > radius]], ___] -> 
           {} (* remove unwanted radial tick labels *),
     Style[Line[{Scaled[_, a_], _Scaled}] /; Norm[a] > radius, Except[{}]] -> 
           {} (* remove unwanted radial ticks *),
     Text[t_, Offset[a_, b : Except[_Scaled]], c___] :> 
          Text[t, Offset[a, scale b], c] (* move angular labels towards new axis*),
     Line[{{0, 0}, a : {_, _}}] :>
       Line[{{0, 0}, scale a}] (* crop the radial axis and angular gridlines *),
     Style[Line[x_], {}] :>
      {Line[x /. { {{a_, b_}, Scaled[c_, d_]} :> 
          {scale {a, b}, Scaled[c, scale d]} (* relocate minor angular ticks *),
      Scaled[a_, b_] :> Scaled[a, scale b] (* relocate major angular ticks *)}]}}] @ #]&
```