# Unable to locate PolarAxesOrigin at its correct place

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

I found sometimes I cannot locate `PolarAxesOrigin` at its correct place which I defined.

For example,

```
PolarPlot[Sqrt[n], {n, 1, 100}, PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", {#, #} & /@ Range[0, 15]}, PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/6, 13}]
```

returns
[image: possible bug in polaraxesorigin]
.
Obviously, the shown origin is placed at $r=15$, not at $r=13$.

Why does it happen? Could I avoid getting the wrong origin?

**Update**

Sorry. I found there is a [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39104/disable-rounding-up-of-polaraxesorigin) which refers to this problem as a bug. However, Has Wolfram neglected the bug for eight years? If so, should I make axes by hand?

**Remedy for the problem**

Although you can see a great answer below, but I add my remedy including some corrections and some improvements.

```
ClearAll[fixPolarAxesCT]

fixPolarAxesCT[plot_, 
  radius_] := (Module[{scale = 
     radius/Max@Cases[plot, Circle[_, r_, _] :> r, All]},
   MapAt[
    (*remove unwanted PolarGridLines*)
    ReplaceAll[#, Circle[{0, 0}, r_ /; r > radius, {0, 2 Pi}] -> {}] &,
    MapAt[
     ReplaceAll[#, {Text[i_, 
          Offset[a_, Scaled[b_, c_ /; Abs[c[[1]]] > radius]], 
          k___] -> {} (*remove unwanted radial tick labels*), 
        Style[Line[{Scaled[_, a_], _Scaled}] /; Norm[a] > radius, 
          Except[{}]] -> {} (*remove unwanted radial ticks*), 
        Line[{{0, 0}, a : {_, _}}] :> 
         Line[{{0, 0}, scale a}] (*crop the radial axis*)}] &,
     (MapAt[
       ReplaceAll[#, {Circle[c_, r_, a_] :> 
           Circle[c, radius, a] (*change angular axis radius*), 
          Text[t_, Offset[a_, b : Except[_Scaled]], c___] :> 
           Text[t, Offset[a, scale b], 
            c] (*move angular labels towards new axis*), 
          Style[Line[x_], dir_] :> 
           Style[Line[
             x /. {{{a_, b_}, Scaled[c_, d_]} :> {scale {a, b}, 
                 Scaled[c, scale d]} (*relocate minor angular ticks*),
                
               Scaled[a_, b_] :> 
                Scaled[a, scale b] (*relocate major angular ticks*)}],
             dir] }] &, plot
       , {1, 7, 1}])
     , {1, 7, 2}]
    , {1, 1, 2}]]
  )
```

You can use this function as

```
plot = PolarPlot[Sqrt[n], {n, 1, 100}, PolarAxes -> True, PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", {#, #} & /@ Range[0, 15]}, PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/6, 13}];

fixedplot = fixPolarAxesCT[plot, 13]
```

(an example).
Note that the `fixedPolarAxesCT` is compatible with both `PolarPlot` and `ListPolarPlot` (the original answer is also compathible with them.).
Furthermore, this can also be applied when you are using `PolarGridLines`, customized `PolarTicks`, and customized `TicksStyle`. Finally, **thanks again to kglr!!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a consequence of *excessive smarts* in polar axes code that  seems to be picking a *"nice"* number for radial axis range overriding user specifications.

A work-around is to post-process `PolarPlot` output to modify the positions of angular axis, angular ticks and tick labels and to remove the unwanted radial ticks/labels:

```
ClearAll[fixPolarAxes]

fixPolarAxes[radius_] := 
  Module[{maxradius = Max @ Cases[#, Circle[_, r_, _] :> r, All], scale},
   scale = radius / maxradius;
   ReplaceAll[
    {Circle[c_, maxradius, a_] :> Circle[c, radius, a] (* change angular axis radius *),
     Circle[_, r_/; r > radius,_] -> {} (* remove unwanted radial gridlines *),
     Text[_, Offset[_, Scaled[_, a_ /; Norm[a] > radius]], ___] -> 
           {} (* remove unwanted radial tick labels *),
     Style[Line[{Scaled[_, a_], _Scaled}] /; Norm[a] > radius, Except[{}]] -> 
           {} (* remove unwanted radial ticks *),
     Text[t_, Offset[a_, b : Except[_Scaled]], c___] :> 
          Text[t, Offset[a, scale b], c] (* move angular labels towards new axis*),
     Line[{{0, 0}, a : {_, _}}] :>
       Line[{{0, 0}, scale a}] (* crop the radial axis and angular gridlines *),
     Style[Line[x_], {}] :>
      {Line[x /. { {{a_, b_}, Scaled[c_, d_]} :> 
          {scale {a, b}, Scaled[c, scale d]} (* relocate minor angular ticks *),
      Scaled[a_, b_] :> Scaled[a, scale b] (* relocate major angular ticks *)}]}}] @ #]&
```

***Examples:***

```
pp = PolarPlot[Sqrt[n], {n, 1, 100}, 
    PolarAxes -> True, 
    PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", {#, #} & /@ Range[0, 15]}, 
    PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/6, 13}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
fixPolarAxes[13] @ pp
```

[image]

```
fixPolarAxes[11] @ pp
```

[image]

An example with polar gridlines and custom polar ticks:

```
SeedRandom[7];

pp2 = PolarPlot[Sqrt[n], {n, 1, 100}, 
    PolarAxes -> True, 
    PolarTicks -> {Sort[RandomSample[Subdivide[0, 360, 36], 20]] Degree, 
      {#, #} & /@ Sort[ RandomSample[Range[0, 24], 10]]}, 
    PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/6, 13}, 
    PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
    PolarGridLines -> Automatic, 
    GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
    ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
fixPolarAxes[13] @ pp2
```

[image]

```
fixPolarAxes[11] @ pp2
```

[image]

Comment: It looks very nice. Sorry I edited the last sentences while you were writing your kind answer. Don't worry about it please. I'll check your method and respond later.

Comment: Your answer is great, so I close this post. Thank you! Since there is some corrections (e.g. it contains  Norm[a] > 13), I will edit my question and add a final remedy for the problem.

Comment: @Keyspire, `Norm[a]>13` should be `Norm[a]>radius`. Fixed now.

Comment: Thank you! p.s. I made a remedy based on your nice answer for general cases. I don't understand why Wolfram has neglected this problem for a long time.

Comment: @Keyspire It is worth to report the problem to the support.

Comment: Great work! Very usefull.